# How to make a double grouping in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

For the first time familiar with MongoDB, the question arose when grouping data.

Given data for two days:

```
db.test.insert({
    "_id" : ObjectId("13edebb315d8952400407343"),
    "create_at" : ISODate("2012-12-19T12:00:00.000Z"),
    "item" : {
        "tags" : [ 
            "aaaa"
        ],
        "event" : "accepted",
    }
});

db.test.insert({
    "_id" : ObjectId("13edebb39e60c73800b35727"),
    "create_at" : ISODate("2012-12-19T12:05:00.000Z"),
    "item" : {
        "tags" : [ 
            "aaaa"
        ],
        "event" : "delivered"
    }
});

db.test.insert({
    "_id" : ObjectId("13edebb315d8952400407344"),
    "create_at" : ISODate("2012-12-19T13:40:00.000Z"),
    "item" : {
        "tags" : [ 
            "bbbb"
        ],
        "event" : "accepted",
    }
});

db.test.insert({
    "_id" : ObjectId("13edebb39e60c73800b35728"),
    "create_at" : ISODate("2012-12-19T13:45:00.000Z"),
    "item" : {
        "tags" : [ 
            "bbbb"
        ],
        "event" : "delivered"
    }
});

db.test.insert({
    "_id" : ObjectId("13edebb315d8952400407345"),
    "create_at" : ISODate("2012-12-20T16:30:00.000Z"),
    "item" : {
        "tags" : [],
        "event" : "accepted",
    }
});

db.test.insert({
    "_id" : ObjectId("13edebb39e60c73800b35729"),
    "create_at" : ISODate("2012-12-20T16:35:00.000Z"),
    "item" : {
        "tags" : [],
        "event" : "delivered"
    }
});
```

The output need to get the result:

```
{
  "total_count": 6
  "items": [
    {
      "total_count": 2,
      "created_at": "Wed, 19 Dec 2012 00:00:00 GMT",
      "tags": {
        "aaaa": 1,
        "bbbb": 1
      },
      "event": "sent"
    },
    {
      "total_count": 2,
      "created_at": "Wed, 19 Dec 2012 00:00:00 GMT",
      "tags": {
        "aaaa": 1,
        "bbbb": 1
      },
      "event": "delivered"
    },
    {
      "total_count": 1,
      "created_at": "Wed, 20 Dec 2012 00:00:00 GMT",
      "tags": {},
      "event": "sent"
    },
    {
      "total_count": 1,
      "created_at": "Wed, 20 Dec 2012 00:00:00 GMT",
      "tags": {},
      "event": "delivered"
    }
}
```

Still managed to form part of the necessary data, request:

```
db.test.aggregate([ 
  {$group:      
   {          
     _id:{event:'$item.event', doy:{$dayOfYear:'$create_at'} },
     total_count:{$sum:1},
     created_at:{$first: '$create_at'},
     tags: {$addToSet: '$item.tags'}
   },
  },
  {$project:{total_count:1,  _id:0, event:'$_id.event', created_at:1, tags:1}}
])
```

But how to get the necessary information about the tags an array of tags and their number? 
As well as the date to indicate the beginning of day 00:00:00?

Comment: Could you clarify what the output you want is? Where does the `supporta` tag come from? Where do the `bbbb` tags go in your desired output? Are you trying to return, for each day and event type, the set of tags with counts?

Comment: Hello, made a mistake in the description of the tag `supporta` == `bbbb` (fixed data in question).
True. Trying to return events for each day, indicating the found tags and their quantity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wdberkeley` made a good analysis at this question. I add mine below:

1. Elements(such as "aaaa") in tags will be as a key in final sub-document. I'm not aware that aggregation pipeline can do this.
2. Output requires the form of `tags:{tag:count, ...}`, so $unwind operator will be used if in pipeline operation style.Output requires documents with empty tags still need to save, but $unwind operator will ignore these documents.
3. JS code is prohibited in pipeline operation, but pipeline operation can't implement that date format(such as `"created_at" : "Wed, 20 Dec 2012 00:00:00 GMT"`).

**Conclusion: use mapReduce instead of aggregation pipeline.**
The following code passed in mongo shell.

```
function map() {
    var date = this.create_at;
    var dateStr = date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-"
            + date.getDate();
    var tags = {};
    var tagsTemp = this.item.tags;
    if (tagsTemp != null) {
        for (var x = 0; x < tagsTemp.length; x++) {
            var tag = tagsTemp[x];
            var count = tags[tag];
            count = (count == null) ? 1 : (count + 1);
            tags[tag] = count;
        }
    }
    emit({
        event : this.item.event,
        dateStr : dateStr
    }, {
        total_count: 1,
        tags : tags
    });
}

function reduce(key, values) {
    var tags = {};
    var total_count = 0;
    values.forEach(function(value) {
        for ( var tag in value.tags) {
            var count = tags[tag];
            if (count == null)
                count = 0;
            tags[tag] = count + value.tags[tag];
        }
        total_count += value.total_count;
    });
    return {
        total_count: total_count,
        tags : tags
    };
}


function finalHandle(key, reduceValue) {
    reduceValue.create_at = new Date(key.dateStr).toUTCString();
    reduceValue.event = key.event;
    return reduceValue;
}

var mr = db.test.mapReduce(map, reduce, {finalize: finalHandle, out:{inline:1}});

var total = 0;
var items = [];

mr.results.forEach(function(x) {
    items.push(x.value);
    total += x.value.total_count;
});

printjson({total_count: total, items: items});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple aggregation query to get you started. It gets most of what you want, but in a bit of a different form.

```
> db.test.aggregate([
    { "$unwind" : "$item.tags" }, 
    { "$group" : 
        { "_id" : { 
            "event" : "$item.event", 
            "day" : { "$dayOfYear" : "$create_at" }, 
            "tag" : "$item.tags" 
            }, 
        "total_count" : { "$sum" : 1 } 
        } 
    }
])
{ "_id" : { "event" : "delivered", "day" : 354, "tag" : "bbbb" }, "total_count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "event" : "accepted", "day" : 354, "tag" : "bbbb" }, "total_count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "event" : "delivered", "day" : 354, "tag" : "aaaa" }, "total_count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "event" : "accepted", "day" : 354, "tag" : "aaaa" }, "total_count" : 1 }
```

Since you want a count of the number of documents by (event, tag, day), this aggregation query computes one document with the required count per unique triple (event, tag, day), which is the most straightforward way to do it. The total count is just the number of results of the aggregation.

To put the day back in as a date, I think you will have to do something client-side, as I'm not aware of any aggregation pipeline operators that produce a date. Still, it's not difficult since you can output all of the relevant date information by changing the `$group` stage and using `$project`. You could reconstruct a string date in the pipeline if you wanted to.

You'll notice the documents without tags aren't counted. This is a necessary consequence of the `$unwind`. The simplest way around it would be to have a dummy tag that represents "no tag". Working around purely through the aggregation framework is going to be messy.

Finally, just one thing I want to point out in case it might be forgotten: if you group on `$dayOfYear`, if your data spans multiple years you may group together docs from different years. Make sure that is what you intend, or add more date information into the group key `_id`.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your comment. Yes, indeed part of the problem can be solved by using `$unwind`, but perhaps there is a more elegant solution? - double grouping data, or the use of additional functions. Also don't understand why design `tags : {"$addToSet" : { "users" : { "$each" : '$item.tags' } } }` is not possible to correctly choose the values from the array.

Comment: Elegance is the luxury of the experienced, and isn't always seen as the same thing by everyone. I think the above approximates elegance with the "no tag" tag fix, because it is so simple. What would be elegant to you, and what is inelegant about the above? `$each` is an update operator, not a possible `$group` operator.